# ошибка 404 при редиректе после аутентификации

Tags: php, пути

Поменял структуру проекта. Вынес папку vendor за папку проекта public. Возникла проблема с путями. т.к. работаю на локалке, то сделал файл с константами путей и пр

**config.php**

```php
define('__DIR_PUBLIC__', '/Tipo-Blog/public');
define('__DIR_SYSTEM__', '/Tipo-Blog');
```

Когда человек авторизовался делаю редирект на страницу:

**check.php**

```
  header("refresh: 1; url=index.php");
  exit();
```

Но возвращает ошибку 404 и путь http://localhost/public/
А должен возвращать путь http://localhost/Tipo-Blog/public/index.php

Файл check.php находится в одной директории с индексным.

Пробовал прописать путь вот так, но тоже не помогло, возвращается тот же самый http://localhost/public/

```php
        $url = __DIR_PUBLIC__."/index.php";
        echo '<br>'.$url; // url возвращает /Tipo-Blog/public/index.php
        header("refresh: 1; url=".$url);
        exit();
```

[image: Структура глобал]

[image: Структура public]

Comment: header("Location: $url"); - так перенаправление, а что у Вас - это обновление с перенаправлением.  А так - маловато информации - что там сломалось при выносе, как было организовано - все в тумане.

Comment: @coder, добавил скрины структуры проекта. Не подскажете?  Я сейчас не понимаю, почему редирект не работает и так, и так. Ведь index находится там же, где и check.php, `header("Location:index.php")`должно быть достаточно

Comment: Непонятен смысл и цель -  что у Вас находится в этих папках - public и vendor, каковы взаимосвязи, что в htaccess, какова логика изначальной инсталляции проекта.

Comment: @coder, папку public можно увидеть на втором скрине. В папке vendor пока 2 файла - сам config.php, о котором я писал и .htaccess, в котором просто написано `Options All -Indexes
Deny from all`

Comment: Что Вы хотите получить в итоге? И счего все начиналось - это Вы сами структуру создали, или изначально что устанавливали?

Comment: Вы хотите изменить корневую директорию проекта?

Comment: @coder, я хочу получить редирект на главную страницу, после авторизации пользователя. Я не понимаю куда девается фраза tipo-blog из урла, когда даже константа `__DIR_PUBLIC__`, описанная в конфиге имеет фразу tipo-blog, а в возвращаемом урле ее вообще нет, просто localhost/public. Структура полностью моя. Это мой первый проект на php. Изначально все было в одной папке, без выноса vendor за пределы проекта

Comment: Нет, корень я менять не хочу. Я специально сделал себе переменные путей, от которых хочу скакать

Comment: Вы вынесли за пределы сайта-папки? Где у Вас корневая сайта/проекта и где vendor?

Comment: Гляньте первый скрин. Там папка самого проекта, где находятся две папки vendor (закрытая ото всех папка) и public (где и расположены файлы сайта).

Comment: Вижу это - не вижу в этом скрине точки входа - index файла. Без понимания цели - не подскажешь - выносить за пределы сайта что нужно только в особых случаях - например, подключение auto_prepend_file и прочего - для авторизации этого делать не след.